# Error - Electrum wallet RPC method not supported

Tags: json-rpc, electrum

I install Electrum in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip
sudo pip install https://download.electrum.org/2.6.4/Electrum-2.6.4.tar.gz
```

Then I start RPC on port 7777 and run daemon:

```
electrum setconfig rpcport 7777
electrum daemon start
```

I try RPC by curl:

```
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"wallet.create_new_address()","params":[]}' http://127.0.0.1:7777
```

I got error output:

```
{"error": {"message": "Method wallet.create_new_address() not supported.", "code": -32601}, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "curltext"}
```

> I tried the command 'wallet.create_new_address()' which can be executed in GUI console but RPC gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your command.

First, any method you call should not be prefixed by `wallet.` or suffixed by `()`.

Also, there is no RPC method `create_new_address`. If you have a look at `lib/commands.py` you will see that the internal python method `create_new_address()` is called by the RPC method `getunusedaddress`, and only when the parameter `force=true` is given.

With the above in mind, try this:

```
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"getunusedaddress","params":{"force":true}}' http://127.0.0.1:7777
```

The equivalent shell command would be

```
electrum getunusedaddress --force
```

I tried this on electrum 2.8.3. Sadly, it always returns the same address. This is because the address remains unused.